# Get Level from Experience points - Level isn't taken into consideration

Tags: javascript

OK, now my issue is that no matter what I do, it will only present the information as Level 1 instead of the designated level that I try. The code is as follows

```
function XPlevel(XP, level) {
    if((XP >= 0 && XP < 300) && level === 1) {
        level = 1;
    } else if ((XP >= 300 && XP <900) || level === 2) {
        level = 2;
    } else if ((XP >= 900 && XP <2700) || level ===3) {
        level = 3;
    } else if ((XP >= 2700 && XP < 6500) || level === 4){
        level = 4;
    } else if ((XP >= 6500 & XP < 14000) || level === 5){
        level = 5;
    } else if ((XP >= 14000 && XP < 23000) || level === 6) {
        level = 6;
    } else if ((XP >= 23000 && XP < 34000) || level === 7) {
        level = 7;
    } else if ((XP >= 34000 && XP < 48000) || level === 8) {
        level = 8;
    } else if ((XP >= 48000 && XP < 64000) || level === 9) {
        level = 9;
    } else if ((XP >= 64000 && XP < 85000) || level === 10) {
        level = 10;
    } else if ((XP >= 85000 && XP < 100000) || level === 11) {
        level = 11;
    } else if ((XP >= 100000 && XP < 120000) || level === 12) {
        level = 12;
    } else if ((XP >= 120000 && XP < 140000) || level === 13) {
        level = 13;
    } else if ((XP >= 140000 && XP < 165000) || level === 14) {
        level = 14;
    } else if ((XP >= 165000 && XP < 195000) || level === 15) {
        level = 15;
    } else if ((XP >= 195000 && XP < 225000) || level === 16) {
        level = 16;
    } else if ((XP >= 225000 && XP < 265000) || level === 17) {
        level = 17;
    } else if ((XP >= 265000 && XP < 305000) || level === 18) {
        level = 18;
    } else if ((XP >= 305000 && XP < 355000) || level === 19) {
        level = 19;
    } else {
        level = 20;
    }

    return level;
}

XPlevel(XP, level);
```

So when I plug in a character that is Level 5 for instance, it gives me back level 1 instead.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This code... it hurts my eyes...

Comment: Ummmm.... Useful code please

Comment: WOW `XPlevel(XP, level);` is very helpful! JK, show us the values you're passing to the function!

Comment: not quite clear what you want to achieve. Can you please provide some examples of input and desired output?

Comment: Where are you declaring `level`?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you use `&&` only for level 1 but `||` everywhere else?

Comment: There are plenty of values for which that function returns `5`: `XPlevel(6500); XPlevel(13999); XPlevel(0,5);` all return `5`. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: What should this function do after all? It seems you already have a `level` that you can pass in, how is that different from the result?

Comment: LOOK! Your code you provided us works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/20/

Comment: What are the values that you are passing on both variables? For me it looks like the problem is on the values that you are passing in to the function...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, never code like this, never have multiple `if-else` statements that make semantically similar checks that could be written using an array or hash table in a few lines.

Your function could be re-written like this:

```
var xp_required = [0, 300, 900, 2700, 6500]; // ...etc, you fill this table with the XP required to be at Level = index + 1 (indices start at 0 in Arrays).
 // XP for level:  1   2    3    4     5  ...
function getLevel(xp) {
   for(var level = xp_required.length - 1; level >= 0; --level) {
     if(xp >= xp_required[level] {
        return level + 1; // The +1 is needed because Array's index starts at 0 but levels start at 1
     }
   }
   console.log("XP value can not be negative. The given value was: " + xp);
   return 0;
}
```

The `for` loop starts at the **highest** level and checks if the `XP` is enough for the player to be considered that level. If it's not, it means that the player is actually a lower level, thus decrementing the level value to be checked (until we reach index 0 which means Level 1). This means that once we get to the first level for which the XP sufficies it means that is indeed the correct level.

As a note, this could be improved by doing a binary search instead of a linear search, but I assume that this function is not called that often so the `O(max_level)` complexity is good enough.

Also, why is `level` both an input and output value for your function?

Answer (score 0):

(Beside the XP stuff...) you're basically doing `if level == 1 return 1` which is nonsensical.
If you already know the `level` than logically you don't need to check for the level.

The simplest & fastest way to **get a `level` out of an array of XP values**:

```
function getLevel(XP) {
  var LV = 0;
  [0, 300, 900, 2700, 6500, 14000].some(function(v, i) {
    LV = i;        // Level = index
    return v > XP; // We have the LV value! Break out of loop (if condition is met)!
  });
  return LV;
}
```

Use like

```
var level = getLevel(2699);  // 3
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some